# ionic gradle issue with version

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I've reading a lot of stuff related to gradle but no success.

When I build the project in Terminal, it arises the following error:

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application'] Minimum
>   supported Gradle version is 2.14.1.  Current version is 2.13. If using
>   the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
>   /Users/mavillar/Dropbox/stlfinder_ionic/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
>   to gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

As indicated in error message, I go to the gradle-wrapper.properties file and change the version and when build again, it change to its initial version.

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

- ionic cordova plugin save
- ionic cordova platform rm android
- ionic cordova platform add android

It works for me